# Windows schedules task creation issue with powershell

Tags: powershell, escaping, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to script windows scheduled task creation with powershell, where the schedules tasks call powershell scripts that are in a directory that contains a space. So i need to create with a /tr argument like powershell.exe -noninteractive -command "& 'c:\temp\program files\a.ps1'"

Here is a sample of what i have tried

```
# Create the script file the schedule task will call, note path contains a space
'set-content c:\temp\program files\a.log "Just done @ $(get-date)"' > 'c:\temp\program files\a.ps1'

$scriptFilePath = 'c:\temp\program files\a.ps1';
$userName = read-host 'user name'; # will need log on as batch rights 
$userPassword = read-host 'user password';

# The following looks good but schtasks args gets messed up so no creation
$taskToRun = "c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noninteractive -command `"& '$scriptFilePath'`"";  
$taskToRun
schtasks /create /tn 'ATest' /ru $userName /rp $userPassword /sc MINUTE /mo 1 /st '00:00' /f /tr $taskToRun;

# Gets imported but mangles the tr so instead of 
$taskToRun = 'c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noninteractive -command \"& ''' + $scriptFilePath + '''\"';
$taskToRun
schtasks /create /tn 'ATest' /ru $userName /rp $userPassword /sc MINUTE /mo 1 /st '00:00' /f /tr $taskToRun;
```

If anyone knows how to escape correctly, i would appreciate a hint

Thanks in advance

Pat

Comment: Powershell doesn't require semicolon row terminator. Use `;` only when you wish to have more than one statement on a row.

Comment: I know they are not needed, just a habit

Comment: any final solution with full source code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd trade the -command option for -file:

```
$taskToRun = "c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noninteractive -file ""$scriptFilePath"""
```

Also, the PowershellPack has a TaskScheduler module that's makes task scheduling much easier:

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerShellPack

[UPDATE] Thanks

Perfect, just needed to escape with a single quote rather than double quote

```
$taskToRun = "c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noninteractive -file '$scriptFilePath'";
```